# How to tell if a process is categorized as [background process] in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, process

The following code is from google:

```
 Const strComputer = "." 
  Dim objWMIService, colProcessList
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
  Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Process.exe'")
  For Each objProcess in colProcessList 
    objProcess.Terminate() 
  Next
```

Is there a way to tell if *objProcess* is background process or App as shown below?

[image]